# Exposing 3rd Party C++ Functions and Classes

Tags: c++, linker

I'm writing a C++ application that makes heavy use of OpenCV. Unfortunately, some of the OpenCV code I'd like to make use of hasn't been exposed by their API. In particular, there is a struct LBPEvaluator::Feature in cascadedetect.cpp (quoted below) that I'd like to make use of. I know I can't simply "#include cascadedetect.cpp" as it will confuse the linker with multiply defined symbols. I assume there is a more elegant solution than copying, pasting, and renaming the code into one of my source files? **What is the general strategy for accessing 3rd party C++ functions and classes that aren't exposed by the 3rd party's API?**

Many thanks in advance.

Specific code I'm trying to use:

```
class LBPEvaluator : public FeatureEvaluator
{
public:
    struct Feature
    {
        Feature();
        Feature( int x, int y, int _block_w, int _block_h  ) : 
        rect(x, y, _block_w, _block_h) {}

        int calc( int offset ) const;
        void updatePtrs( const Mat& sum );
        bool read(const FileNode& node );

        Rect rect; // weight and height for block
        const int* p[16]; // fast
    };

    LBPEvaluator();
    virtual ~LBPEvaluator();

    virtual bool read( const FileNode& node );
    virtual Ptr<FeatureEvaluator> clone() const;
    virtual int getFeatureType() const { return FeatureEvaluator::LBP; }

    virtual bool setImage(const Mat& image, Size _origWinSize);
    virtual bool setWindow(Point pt);

    int operator()(int featureIdx) const
    { return featuresPtr[featureIdx].calc(offset); }
    virtual int calcCat(int featureIdx) const
    { return (*this)(featureIdx); }
private:
    Size origWinSize;
    Ptr<vector<Feature> > features;
    Feature* featuresPtr; // optimization
    Mat sum0, sum;
    Rect normrect;

    int offset;
};    


inline LBPEvaluator::Feature :: Feature()
{
    rect = Rect();
    for( int i = 0; i < 16; i++ )
        p[i] = 0;
}

inline int LBPEvaluator::Feature :: calc( int offset ) const
{
    int cval = CALC_SUM_( p[5], p[6], p[9], p[10], offset );

    return (CALC_SUM_( p[0], p[1], p[4], p[5], offset ) >= cval ? 128 : 0) |   // 0
           (CALC_SUM_( p[1], p[2], p[5], p[6], offset ) >= cval ? 64 : 0) |    // 1
           (CALC_SUM_( p[2], p[3], p[6], p[7], offset ) >= cval ? 32 : 0) |    // 2
           (CALC_SUM_( p[6], p[7], p[10], p[11], offset ) >= cval ? 16 : 0) |  // 5
           (CALC_SUM_( p[10], p[11], p[14], p[15], offset ) >= cval ? 8 : 0)|  // 8
           (CALC_SUM_( p[9], p[10], p[13], p[14], offset ) >= cval ? 4 : 0)|   // 7
           (CALC_SUM_( p[8], p[9], p[12], p[13], offset ) >= cval ? 2 : 0)|    // 6
           (CALC_SUM_( p[4], p[5], p[8], p[9], offset ) >= cval ? 1 : 0);
}

inline void LBPEvaluator::Feature :: updatePtrs( const Mat& sum )
{
    const int* ptr = (const int*)sum.data;
    size_t step = sum.step/sizeof(ptr[0]);
    Rect tr = rect;
    CV_SUM_PTRS( p[0], p[1], p[4], p[5], ptr, tr, step );
    tr.x += 2*rect.width;
    CV_SUM_PTRS( p[2], p[3], p[6], p[7], ptr, tr, step );
    tr.y += 2*rect.height;
    CV_SUM_PTRS( p[10], p[11], p[14], p[15], ptr, tr, step );
    tr.x -= 2*rect.width;
    CV_SUM_PTRS( p[8], p[9], p[12], p[13], ptr, tr, step );
}

bool LBPEvaluator::Feature :: read(const FileNode& node )
{
    FileNode rnode = node[CC_RECT];
    FileNodeIterator it = rnode.begin();
    it >> rect.x >> rect.y >> rect.width >> rect.height;
    return true;
}

LBPEvaluator::LBPEvaluator()
{
    features = new vector<Feature>();
}
LBPEvaluator::~LBPEvaluator()
{
}

bool LBPEvaluator::read( const FileNode& node )
{
    features->resize(node.size());
    featuresPtr = &(*features)[0];
    FileNodeIterator it = node.begin(), it_end = node.end();
    for(int i = 0; it != it_end; ++it, i++)
    {
        if(!featuresPtr[i].read(*it))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

Ptr<FeatureEvaluator> LBPEvaluator::clone() const
{
    LBPEvaluator* ret = new LBPEvaluator;
    ret->origWinSize = origWinSize;
    ret->features = features;
    ret->featuresPtr = &(*ret->features)[0];
    ret->sum0 = sum0, ret->sum = sum;
    ret->normrect = normrect;
    ret->offset = offset;
    return ret;
}

bool LBPEvaluator::setImage( const Mat& image, Size _origWinSize )
{
    int rn = image.rows+1, cn = image.cols+1;
    origWinSize = _origWinSize;

    if( image.cols < origWinSize.width || image.rows < origWinSize.height )
        return false;

    if( sum0.rows < rn || sum0.cols < cn )
        sum0.create(rn, cn, CV_32S);
    sum = Mat(rn, cn, CV_32S, sum0.data);
    integral(image, sum);

    size_t fi, nfeatures = features->size();

    for( fi = 0; fi < nfeatures; fi++ )
        featuresPtr[fi].updatePtrs( sum );
    return true;
}

bool LBPEvaluator::setWindow( Point pt )
{
    if( pt.x < 0 || pt.y < 0 ||
        pt.x + origWinSize.width >= sum.cols-2 ||
        pt.y + origWinSize.height >= sum.rows-2 )
        return false;
    offset = pt.y * ((int)sum.step/sizeof(int)) + pt.x;
    return true;
}

Ptr<FeatureEvaluator> FeatureEvaluator::create(int featureType)
{
    return featureType == HAAR ? Ptr<FeatureEvaluator>(new HaarEvaluator) :
        featureType == LBP ? Ptr<FeatureEvaluator>(new LBPEvaluator) : Ptr<FeatureEvaluator>();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My general strategy is to **not** access 3rd party functions and/or classes that are not exposed through their public interface.

The fact that they are not public means that they could change between a release and the next one, so you should not put a dependency over it.

**EDIT**
If it's open source code (and/or you have permission to copy it) and you really need this functionality, you could extract the relevant part and maintain it personally. This shields you from the fact that the original code could change. You will have same code duplicated, violating [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), but I guess that this can be tolerated.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you shouldn't. For a well-debugged API, if something isn't exposed there's probably a damn good reason why it isn't.

I have come across a few instances where it had to be done. Always in internal code where I didn't have easy access to the repository to change the API. In those cases, generally I just put the profile of the needed routine at the top of the source file that needs it, as ugly as possible. Then it should be "fixed" to be public at the earliest opportunity.

I suppose it is possible that you've found a problem in the API where a private method needs to be public. If that's the case, you really ought to do the equivalent of the above and talk to the maintainers of the API about making the method public. That would also give them a chance to tell you why this is a really bad idea (if it is).